# Can't get ReactJS to Compile ReactJS JSX on Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, reactjs, .net-core

I am developing a C# ASPNet Core web app on Mac OSX using .Net Core App 1.1.0. I have referenced the React.AspNet (3.0.0) NuGet package and followed this [ReactJS tutorial](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html). I know the tutorial works because I've managed to get everything working on Windows. However when running on OSX I get the following runtime error

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/js/tutorial.jsx
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL0UDE81SLFD": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.ReactEnvironment ---> React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.JavaScriptEngineFactory ---> React.Exceptions.VroomJsInitialisationException: Failed to initialise VroomJs. This is most likely caused by the native library (libVroomJsNative.so) being out of date or your system lacking a compatible version of V8. Please run Mono with the `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug` environment variable for more debugging information, and refer to the ReactJS.NET Mono documentation at http://reactjs.net/guides/mono.html for further debugging hints.

 More details: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at React.JavaScriptEngineUtils.EnsureEngineFunctional[TEngine,TException](Func`2 exceptionFactory)
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetFactory(JsEngineSwitcher jsEngineSwitcher, Boolean allowMsie)
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory..ctor(JsEngineSwitcher jsEngineSwitcher, IReactSiteConfiguration config, IFileSystem fileSystem)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.SingletonFactory.GetObject(Type requestedType, TinyIoCContainer container, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.CustomObjectLifetimeFactory.GetObject(Type requestedType, TinyIoCContainer container, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
   at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType]()
   at React.AspNet.BabelFileMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 11.2943ms 200
```

I've got to the point where I've run out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice on this Github issue comment ([#338](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/338#issuecomment-257238034)). I was able to resolve this in my own project by running the following command:

`dotnet add package JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore && dotnet add package JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.Native.osx-x64`